# Gevent clustering, what RPC do you use?

Tags: signals, messaging, rpc, gevent

I am experiementing Gevent with multiple worker process for a website. So if one long running greenlet task is been executed at process A, another wsgi web requests arrives at process B and I need to query the greenlet state at process A, are there any well-known solutions?

Comment: Hi I came across this question searching for answer the same problem. What solution did you end up with?

Comment: @Ryan Not much. Currently simply using a BOOL as a flag in db field as simple task queue.